# Dynamically Create Sections in Swift UI List (Using CoreData)

Tags: swift, listview, core-data, swiftui

I have a multiple `Entry` objects (entries) stored in CoreData that I access as a list given by a FetchRequest in my ContentView.
All entries have a date and I want to not only put all entries in a list (I have achieved that) but put them in their right SwiftUI section (that correspond to the day of the entries) in that list.

Basically, my question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574847/how-to-dynamically-create-sections-in-a-swiftui-list-foreach-and-avoid-unable-t), but I am not sure how to implement it as I am using CoreData and don't have a user data object.

I thought about introducing a model of the list view and bind it to the list view.
I would need to incorporate the fetch request into the model and use an attribute/function to provide an `[[Entry]]` attribute to the view, right?

How exactly would I do this? How do I continuously maintain an `[[Entry]]` attribute in the model that I can access/(add to)/(delete from) from the view?

The current state of my Xcode project is almost exactly like presented in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BZdQmHV4MQ); actually I just want to expand on this video as an exercise.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59180698/3985749).  Does the answer address your question?

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, thanks, that helped quite a bit. However, I feel weird incorporating more and more logic into the view file, so alternative answers are very welcome, too!