# how to make a list with sections by year?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a Core Data entity with a Date type attribute. How to make a list containing all instances of this entity and divided into sections by year?

Similar to the screenshot:
[image: an example]

Comment: This might help you: [How to dynamically create sections in a SwiftUI List/ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574847/how-to-dynamically-create-sections-in-a-swiftui-list-foreach-and-avoid-unable-t)

Comment: @pawello2222 thanks, this link was really helpful